# I got new function for API Controller and it's not working at this

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-routing, laravel-api

I coded `update` status for `category`. I got a new function in an API
Controller, so when I click submit it is not working.

This is solved when I move to category.update, but I can't because that function is used for something else.

##### `web.php`

```php
Route::patch('category/{$category}', 'Admin\CategoryController@change')
    ->name('category.change');
Route::resource('category', 'Admin\CategoryController')
    ->middleware('loggedin');
```

This is the new function for API Controller:

```
public function change($category, Request $request)
{
    $cate = Category::find($category);
    if ($cate->category_status == 0) {
        $cate->category_status = 1;
        $cate->save();
    } else {
        $cate->category_status = 0;
        $cate->save();
    }

    return back()->with('success', 'Success!');
}
```

##### `list.blade.php`

```html
<form autocomplete="off" action="{{ route('category.change', [$cate->category_id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @method('PATCH')
    @csrf
    <button class="fa fa-eye" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: in your route the $ sign is not necessary `...patch('category/{category}'...`

Comment: @JuanEizmendi thanks for that but i have a new problem is category.change not defined,

Comment: when you pass an array to de route helper need to be keyed with params names, in this case, is the only one so you can just pass the number. `route('category.change', $cate->category_id)`

Comment: @JuanEizmendi for a route with one parameter, this makes no difference. You can pass the value as an integer, an indexed array, or an associative array. I just tested `route("users.edit", 23);`, `route("users.edit", [23]);`, and `route("users.edit", ["user"=>23]);` on my app. All had same results.

Comment: @miken32 in Laravel 8 (maybe 7) - route with require array with named param - even for one param

Comment: I tested in Laravel 8 @Maksim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in route, delete $

```
Route::patch('category/{category}', 'Admin\CategoryController@change')
   ->name('category.change');
```

Second - use route with named param

```
route('category.change', ['category' => $cate->category_id])
```

Third - in controller action Request must be first

```
public function change(Request $request, $category){}
```